# Change detection with RxJs Angular Signals, how to read new data in observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-changedetection, angular-signals

I am attempting to utilise Angular's new Signal feature but struggling with reactivity.

## Current Method

From understanding so far, to work with RxJS and Signals correctly the output of this observable needs to be converted to a signal using the toSignal() function, previously fromObs()

```
  response_signal = toSignal(this.response$ =
     this.apiService.getListApiV1O(
   ))
```

The signal can be read and displayed sucessfully read, likd this:

```
    <div *ngIf="response_signal()">
      <div *ngFor="let item of response_signal().items">
          <label>{{ item.name }}</label>
          <small>{{ item.website }}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Issue**

Here is the point at which I am lost. Typically Subjects/Event Emitters were considered the best solution to ensure reactivity. Signals supposedly have enhanced change detection features. I am however struggling with how they would be implmented here.

Does anyone know how to acheive reactivity if the observable has fresh data?

Comment: When the signal gets a new value, the template will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using `computed`

`response_signal = computed(() => { this.apiService.getListApiV1O() })`

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented this but my template is now blank, as if the data is not being read from the response

Comment: What if you map the value and assign it to the `computed()` method? I've updated my code above

Comment: I acuually think I've found the solution, just remove the `{}` so it can be `response_signal = computed(() => this.apiService.getListApiV1O())`

Comment: I am trying but this doesn't work for me. Whats been dropped here is the toSignal function. I think this ought to be retained in some capacity... A toComputedSignal function if you will

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a stackblitz link with the problem so I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

It is what you need?

```
export class MyComponent {
  apiService = inject(ApiService);
  response$ = this.apiService.getListApiV1O();
  response_signal = toSignal(this.response$, { initialValue: {items: []} });
}
```

1. You describe your observable.
2. You describe your signal correctly with an initialValue
3. You use your signal in a template than

You need an initial value or the code will fail, because you try to read `items` of undefined.

I also prepared a small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vjpukj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Tell me if you have any issues with that.